# What does a cached result mean?

Tags: ajax

I am new to web development and i am learning AJAX from [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp). While learning GET request it says that the following may give you a cached result:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

To avoid this, add a unique ID to the URL:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp?t=" + Math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

What does cached result means.? I went through the entire example but could'nt understand, When should i use a unique ID as given in the second method?

Comment: You should most definitely not be learning anything from w3schools. To find out why, take a look at http://w3fools.com/.

Comment: reasons: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser can cache Http responses by their **Uniqe URL**, so at the next times you visit a site the browser won't send an http request, but display the last response for this URL from its cache storage.

When you create URL with random factor (in this case there is an querystring variable name `t` with **random value**), this prevents the browser from caching the response.

**The first case's browser cached URLs:**

demo_get.asp

demo_get.asp *From cache*

**The second case's browser cached URLs:**

demo_get.asp?r=42350972

demo_get.asp?r=11850753 *No caching*

Answer (score 3):

After making an HTTP GET request, the browser may choose to keep the response it received and, next time it needs to make the same request, instead of making the request, get the response it received earlier and present that instead. This is called [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29).

Since the URL is usually the key by which the browser identifies which cached page to retrieve, one way of breaking this is to always request the same resource using a different URL. This way, the browser will store the response to each URL, but will be very unlikely to retrieve the stored page again, because the new URL is different from the one it used last time to store the response.

Another way to control caching would be to use the [caching capabilities](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) built-in to the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Do browser caches .asp/.jsp pages as well?  Is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: @RakeshJuyal, browsers cache any response, regardless of what server technology was used to generate it.