# what is known as Cached result in AJAX

Tags: ajax

In AJAX ,In some website saying that we may get Cached Result When we use GET method like below.What is the real meaning of cached result.

xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);

Comment: could you rephrase your question?

Comment: It means that the browser locally caches the result and doesn't make a full GET request a second time.  Instead it just shows what it already has locally cached.  This isn't exclusive to AJAX, browsers do this for all requested resources.

Comment: Follow this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069538/what-does-a-cached-result-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we make the AJAX request, we `check the cache object` to see if we've saved this key's  information. If so, `avoid the repetitive AJAX request` and simply return the cached information. If the key does not exist, make the AJAX request and save the result to the cache.

For More Info:

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/

http://blog.artlogic.com/2013/06/27/ajax-caching-transports-compatible-with-jquery-deferred/

Answer (score 0):

By cached result, I think they mean that you may get a result that is cached by the browser. However, if you want an uncached result, the [jquery website](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) says:

cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
Type: Boolean
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests.